# Tinymce-4 error: "File extension is not allowed " when inserting Excel(.xlsx) file in ASP.NET project

Tags: excel, insert, tinymce-4

I am using tinymce-4 plugin in my asp.net application. I have configured web.config file to allow '.xlsx' file to be uploaded like this:

```
 <setting name="AllowedFileExtensions" serializeAs="String">
    <value>'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'txt', 'csv','html','psd','sql','log','fla','xml','ade','adp','ppt','pptx'</value>
  </setting>
```

However, I am getting an error **File extension is not allowed**
when inserting **xlsx** file.

Am I missing something in my web.config file?

Also, for initialization of plugin I am using the following code:

```
 tfm_path = '/common/filemanager';
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea.html-editor',
        plugins: 'advlist anchor autolink charmap code contextmenu directionality fullpage fullscreen image insertdatetime link lists media pagebreak paste print searchreplace spellchecker table webizafilemanager wordcount',
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        language: 'tr_TR'
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried docx and pptx ?  Do those work ?

Comment: @TimWilliams. I tried, they don't work either.